# Replacing all Integers with BigInteger in java

Tags: java, math, int, biginteger

By referring [**this**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658472/set-of-all-n-n-d2-1-d2-2-d2-3-d2-4) question which was in Mathematics stackexchange I tried to write a java program find possible results for it.

```
class testing{

public static void main(String []args){
    for(int Num=36;Num<1000000;Num++){
        int[] Fac=new int[4];       

        for(int Div=1,ar=0;(Div<=Num)&(ar<Fac.length);Div++){

            if((Num % Div)==0){
                Fac[ar]=Div;
                ar++;
            }
        }
        int T=0;
        for(int y:Fac){ 
            y*=y;
            T+=y;
        }
        if(T==Num){
            for(int x:Fac){
                System.out.print( x+",");
            }
            System.out.println(":"+Num);
        }
    }   
}}
```

I have used here `int` data type and checked up to 1000000 numbers. But I found only 130 withing that range which satisfy the necessary conditions of the question. 
I got a question that if there are more examples outside the range of `int` or `long`? Yes, I found that `BigInteger` will come for the rescue. 
But if I want to replace these `Integer` data type values to `BigInteger` object type values, Will I have to code the whole codes again? Or is there any way to convert these int type to BigInteger?

Actually as this is a small source code, It is not harder to write it again wiht `BigInteger`. But what about if we have written a big program with `integers` and later we would need huge integers instead of small integers?

Comment: BigInteger is going to take more memory than an int or long primitive, and be _much_ slower. Like, orders of magnitude slower. For most usages, a long is just fine.

Comment: You cannot overload the usual integer arithmetic operators "+", "-", "*", etc. to work with BigIntegers, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to replace all int/long declarations with BigInteger, and check the library reference to replace the arithmetic assignments with function calls that BigInteger uses, for example

```
T += y;
```

becomes

```
T = T.add(y);
```

Although you should work exclusively using BigInteger to avoid any truncation issues, you can use BigInteger.valueOf(i) to convert int/long types to BigInteger, eg

```
int i = 123;
BigInteger T = BigInteger.valueOf(i)
```

when going in the other direction, only the lower bits are converted (truncation) if the value is too large, with T.longValue(). I recommend reading a BigInteger reference online when coding...

Answer (score 0):

Another question is, which variables do you actually need to be BigIntegers? It is not very common, that a number exceeds the int / long bound.

In your case the Fac variable probably needs to be BigInteger and everything that iterates over it. In a big program you will have to look where you need to use BigIntegers and then you will only use BigIntegers there.

Comment: After we make a variable BigInteger, Can we do operations involving normal `int` number? As an example can we add an `int 10` to `BigInteger 50` ?

Comment: Instead of `myInt += 10;`, you can do: `myBigInt = myBigInt.add(BigInteger.valueOf(10));`or similar.